# VIM без конфигурации как редактор по умолчанию для Git

Tags: git, vim

Мне бы хотелось использовать Vim в качестве редактора по умолчанию при создании коммитов. Но он у меня нагружен некоторым количеством плагинов (нужных) и его запуск занимает секунду-другую. Соответстенно, для того, чтобы написать пару строк в сообщеннии коммита не хочется ждать загрузки VIM и старта всех плагинов.

Я знаю, как установить редактор по умолчанию в Git:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

Запустить Vim без плагинов можно, например, так:

```
vim -u NONE
```

Увы, но первое, что приходит в голову: `git config --global core.editor vim -u NONE` не работает. Что нужно сделать?

Comment: Может кавычки поставить? `git config --global core.editor 'vim -u NONE'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Решение: создаем свой скрипт, который прописываем как редактор.

Это можно сделать из консоли так:

```
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/bare-vim > /dev/null <<\EOF
!#/bin/sh
vim -u NONE "$@"
EOF

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/bare-vim

git config --global core.editor bare-vim
```

**Вариант 2**

`git config --global core.editor 'vim -u NONE'`

это тоже работает:

```
ps -aux | grep vim
...
/bin/sh -c vim -u NONE "$@" vim -u NONE
```